# Want to have a SQL Server run query against a SQL Anywhere DB on another server

Tags: sql-server, sqlanywhere, cross-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 database on one server, and a SQL Anywhere 12 database on another server. I want to schedule a nightly select query that pulls data from the SQL Anywhere DB to the SQL Server DB.

This is all easily done between two SQL Server databases, even on different servers, but I have no option for "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Anywhere" and everything I find on the subject seems to assume that both the SQL Server and the SQL Anywhere DBMS are on the same server. That is not an option for me.

Is there some way I can get and install just what is needed on the SQL Server system to let me get the SQL Anywhere provider option? Legally and without involving additional licensing?

Comment: Quite tricky to find but try installing the client tools in your SQL Server host machine. They include the ODBC drivers.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35857

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Anywhere` is exactly the right one.

This creates the necessary installer:

```
Start Menu\Programs\SQL Anywhere 16\Administration Tools\Deploy to Windows
```

Then just install it on the SQL server and you're ready to go.